# MS Form Recognizer API - Analyze document - Result ID

Tags: c#, azure, azure-form-recognizer

I am trying to use the AZ Form Recognizer API from the [Link Here](https://centralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-2023-02-28-preview/operations/AnalyzeDocument) and I am unable to do the following -

1. Attach PDF's in the testing console. How can we do this?
2. I tried the same API from Postman and attached the PDF for the sake of moving on and now I expected the result to have some 'result ID' that I can use later in my call to API - Analyze result.

The documents [here](https://centralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-2023-02-28-preview/operations/GetAnalyzeDocumentResult) are not indicative of where the result id should be gathered from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [**API Link1**](https://centralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-2023-02-28-preview/operations/AnalyzeDocument) does not support attaching PDF file even if you select application/pdf, Refer below:-

> For **application/json urlSource: "string" for request body paramater is present**:-
>
> [image]
>
> But **for application/pdf there's no request body parameter present:**-
>
> [image]

***So In order to Analyze Invoice with PDF with the above link, Use application/json and enter your invoice github link and the call will be successful you will also receive result ID in the output, Refer below:-***

[**API LINK2 of Analyze Document:-**](https://australiaeast.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-2022-08-31/operations/AnalyzeDocument/console)

As my Form recognizer resource is in Australia I have selected Australia as a region from this [**API Link3**](https://australiaeast.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-2022-08-31/operations/AnalyzeDocument) and entered the parameters like below:-

[image]

**Output:-**

[image]

**Call:-**

```http
    Host 
    Name- australiaeast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
    
    Query paramaters
    
    modelId prebuilt invoice
    
    Headers
    
    Content-Type application/json
    Ocp-Apim-subscription-Key <your API key>
    
    Request body
    
    {
      "urlSource": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-REST-api-samples/master/curl/form-recognizer/sample-invoice.pdf"
    }
```

**HTTP Request:-**

```
POST https://australiaeast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/formrecognizer/documentModels/prebuilt-invoice:analyze?api-version=2022-08-31 HTTP/1.1
Host: australiaeast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
Content-Type: application/json
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••

{
  "urlSource": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-REST-api-samples/master/curl/form-recognizer/sample-invoice.pdf"
}
```

**Response:-**

```http
Operation-Location: https://australiaeast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/formrecognizer/documentModels/prebuilt-invoice/analyzeResults/3305e6d3-2207-4727-8ffa-b04bb536c344?api-version=2022-08-31
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 455
apim-request-id: 3305e6d3-2207-4727-8ffa-b04bb536c344
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-ms-region: Australia East
Date: Wed, 17 May 2023 05:50:28 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

***In the above response:- 3305e6d3-2207-4727-8ffa-b04bb536c344 is the Result ID as given in this [**Rest API**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/formrecognizer/2.0/analyze-receipt-async/analyze-receipt-async?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0)***

Now you can call the GetAnalyze Result API from this [**link**](https://australiaeast.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-2023-02-28-preview/operations/GetAnalyzeDocumentResult/console).

You can add the PDF file in postman request body form-data and call this [**API**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/formrecognizer/2.0/analyze-receipt-async/analyze-receipt-async?tabs=HTTP) Refer below:-

[image]

[image]

```http
POST https://australiaeast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/formrecognizer/v2.0/prebuilt/receipt/analyze

Content-Type:application/pdf
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:6e3xxxxxxxxxx

Body
form-data
Source <file>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed POST a file via Postman to the latest version of the API (v 2023-07-31 as of now). In the Request Body, make sure you select "binary" as the option in Postman, then pick your file from local machine.

You should get a `202 Accepted` HTTP response code once POSTed. Under the Headers section look for this field: `apim-request-id`. This is essentially the "resultId" you are looking for. I agree the documentation is not perfect.